# cucumber keyword to run 100 transactions within certain period

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm newbie to cucumber-java,

I want to run 100 transactions within a second. is there any keyword for cucumber test?

Comment: I guess it will be running one feature file in parallel within a certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

@goutthee Please note that 1. Cucumbr is not a performance testing tool. You might want to have a look tools specific for Performance testing, like Gatling or JMeter. 2. Cucumber doesn't support parallel testing out of the box; you'll need to use a plugin for that, for instance: https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin